# Custom motd for a specific user after logging in via SSH?

Tags: ssh, bash, login

I want to run script upon initial login over SSH that displays some helpful information to the user logging in. However, I don't want this script to run on *every* login. That is, if the user starts `screen` after logging in the custom "motd" shouldn't be run again (nor if subsequent screens are created). Of particular note, the script will need the user's final ENV to work correctly. Is this possible? If so, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in this [ALE thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.user-groups.ale/87855), it is possible to use the user's `${HOME}/.ssh/rc` file for this purpose. The [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/sshd/), in the SSHRC section, explicitly states that you *should not* write to stdout via this rc file, but the following script will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -t 1 ]; then
    # This is scp, sftp, a port forward, or something else
    exit
fi

# Use stderr like the manpage tells you to do
exec 1>&2

echo -e "This is output to stdout via the ${HOME}/.ssh/rc file.\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

`PrintMotd` directive is not allowed within a `Match` block. If all you want is display some helpful info for a specific user when he login, `Banner` directive can do this:

```
Match User <special_user>
    Banner /etc/ssh/banner.txt
```

Comment: He mentioned using the user's env in a script to print this info, does banner support that?  I didn't think it did.

Comment: Indeed. I want to execute a script, not dump a text file to the screen.